# eZ publish search

Tags: migration, ezpublish

I just migrated from eZ Publish 4.4 to 4.7. Everything is working fine but my extension eZSearch ++ v1.0.2 (aka eZSearchPro).

I get the error: "eZSearchEnginePro::addObject() must be compatible with that of ezpSearchEngine::addObject()".

I followed these instructions regarding the migration: http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Upgrading/Direct-upgrading/Direct-upgrading-to-4.7-from-4.1-4.2-4.3-4.4-and-4.5/Direct-upgrading-from-4.4-to-4.7

I don't want to use eZFind instead...

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Max

Answer (score 0):

eZ Publish or the upgrade is not really responsible for your error. The extension you are using, is. The issue you are facing is basically related to the prototype of your eZSearchEnginePro::addObject() method.

Open ezpSearchEngine, look at the addObject method prototype. If it's a public static method then eZSearchEnginePro::addObject() has to be declared the same way, it's it's a private method, then... etc. You also have to check the argument list, which has to have the same formats.

Google "must be compatible with that of", you'll find plenty of stories like your's...